# Emscripten compiled threads seem to be copying references

Tags: c++, multithreading, webassembly, emscripten

I have created a thread that takes by reference an object as follows:

```
void Foo::startThread() {
    this->syncThread.push_back(std::thread(my_thread, ref(*this)));
}
```

my_thread simply prints the pointer value of Foo and increments a counter:

```
void my_thread(Foo& instance) {
    while(true) {
        instance.counter++;
        printf("Address of x in thread is %p\n", (void *)&instance);  
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

If I run the following:

```
Foo * foo = new Foo();
printf("Address of x is %p\n", (void *)&foo);
foo->startThread();
```

I get output as follows:

```
Address of x is 0x9780
Address of x in thread is 0
Address of x in thread is 0
Address of x in thread is 0
```

It seems like the reference is somehow getting copied to the threads stackframe at the null location. This is a big problem as I need the threads to share data ... if the thread is updating a copy then I can't access any of the objects mutated state from the parent thread.
If I try to print foo.counter from main thread I get "0" every time... I am perplexed.

Can anyone help me decipher what is going on?

I am linking as follows:

```
    set_target_properties(a PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-s 'EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=[\"ccall\", \"cwrap\", \"intArrayFromString\", \"allocate\"]' -s WASM=1 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='[_main]'")
```

and have following compile flags:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fexceptions -pthread -std=c++17")
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf("Address of x is %p\n", (void *)&foo);`
foo is alreadh a pointer so you're just printing the local address of the pointer itself and not the address that the pointers points at